# Typescript types for Firebase and Firestore

Tags: typescript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have the following function

```js
export async function onNewMessage(firestore, snapshot, context) {
  console.log(JSON.stringify(snapshot))
}
```

How can I type the variables `firestore`, `snapshot` and `context`? Where is the package with their types?

### EDIT

I am currently using it, is this correct?

```js
import { Firestore, DocumentSnapshot } from '@google-cloud/firestore'
import { EventContext } from 'firebase-functions'

async function onNewMessage(firestore: Firestore, snapshot: DocumentSnapshot, context: EventContext) {
  console.log(JSON.stringify(snapshot))
  console.log(JSON.stringify(context))
}
```

Comment: What kind of packages do you have installed on your project? `firebase` should be enough.

Comment: Well, I saw the package `@firebase/firestore-types` on NPM, but I am not sure if it is official and how to use, there's no README file

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/@firebase/firestore-types README says *This package is not intended for direct usage, and should only be used via the officially supported firebase package.* I believe that's all you really need to do.

Comment: Oh! I didn't notice that

Comment: So... How can I ensure the type? Would be something like this `onNewMessage(firestore: firebase.Firestore...`?

Comment: Most likely yes. Docs have a section on how to import firebase types to a TypeScript project and that you need to enable `allowSyntheticDefaultImports` setting. Once that's done - you'll probably be able to use `firebase.Firestore` as type.

Comment: I added allowSyntheticDefaultImports, now how can I add type to the parameters?

Comment: Does `onNewMessage(firestore: firebase.Firestore...?` work or it doesn't?

Comment: I updated my question with my current usage.

Comment: I don't know it is correct. Does it work? :)

Comment: It works, but I don't know if it's "mostly" correct